# How to do spacing and two decimal places in the same printf

Tags: java, printf

How can I use printf to format spacing AND two decimal places in the same printf?

I can format the spacing using;

```java
System.out.printf("%-20s%-35s%-35s\n", "name : "+shape.getShapeName(),"shape area : "+shape.calculateArea(), "shape perimeter : "+shape.calculatePerimiter());
```

I can format the two decimal places using;

```java
System.out.printf("Name : "+shape.getShapeName()+" shape area : %.2f shape perimeter : %.2f \n",shape.calculateArea(),shape.calculatePerimiter());
```

However, I can't work out doing both at the same time, in the same printf.

Here is the minimal reproducible code;

```java
public class StackOverflowCode {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String shapeName = "Circle";
        double shapeArea = 2.2222222222;
        double shapePerimeter = 5.555555;
        
        System.out.printf("%-20s%-35s%-35s\n", "name : "+shapeName,"shape area : "+shapeArea, "shape perimeter : "+shapePerimeter);
        
        System.out.printf("Name : "+shapeName+" shape area : %.2f shape perimeter : %.2f \n",shapeArea,shapePerimeter);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what effect you desire. Do you mean `%-20.2f` or something like that?

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm looking for 3 columns (String, int, int) and for the two int columns to be of equal length and display the int's as 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StackOverflowCode {



/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
String shapeName = "Circle";
double shapeArea = 2.2222222222;
double shapePerimeter = 5.555555;

System.out.printf("%-20s%-35s%-35s\n", "name : "+shapeName,"shape area : "+shapeArea, "shape perimeter : "+shapePerimeter);

System.out.printf("Name : "+shapeName+" shape area : %.2f shape perimeter : %.2f \n",shapeArea,shapePerimeter);


//spacing and two decimal places in the same printf
System.out.printf( "Name : "+shapeName+"%6s"+" shape area : %.2f %6s shape perimeter : %.2f \n","",shapeArea,"",shapePerimeter);
}
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks. Only challenge I have is in my actual code, is the shape names are longer e.g. 'Rectangle' it throws the spacing off. But otherwise this solves the problem.